# Passing array parameters to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Technique for sending lots of data into stored proc](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/629/technique-for-sending-lots-of-data-into-stored-proc)

I frequently come across the situation where I want to pass an array of Ids as a parameter to a stored procedure.

For example with GetCustomerAccounts stored procedure, the client chooses say 20 customers from a list. I want to then pass these 20 customer Ids to the procedure for it to return their accounts.

Currently I solve this by having a Parameters table. I populate this with my customer Ids and a single Guid ID. This single Guid ID is then passed to the procedure which then joins agains the Parameters table. I don't like this as it involved multiple trips to the database.

Another possibility would be to pass the Ids in a comma separated Varchar parameter. The stored procedure could then parse this string into a temporary table and then join against that. Again that feels pretty nasty.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: [This discussion](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/629/2660) covers the same problem.